# Ошибка скачивания pod on Mac M1

Tags: macos, flutter, dart

Error: To set up CocoaPods for ARM macOS, run:
arch -x86_64 sudo gem install ffi

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.

---

Comment: наверно надо последовать рекомендации, приведённой в тексте сообщения об ошибке.